# How do I set multiple cookies from an Azure function?

Tags: c#, cookies, azure-functions

I'm returning a `HttpResponseMessage` object. I'm setting multiple cookies on my response, like so

```
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue($"a", "content of cookie a");
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Path = $"/l/";

    cookies.Add(cookie);

    cookie = new CookieHeaderValue($"test", "hello");
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Path = $"/l";

    cookies.Add(cookie);

    cookie = new CookieHeaderValue($"b", "content of cookie b");
    cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(1);
    cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie.Path = $"/l/some-folder-path";

    cookies.Add(cookie);

    message.Headers.AddCookies(cookies);
```

It appears that my function is setting the header correctly. Here's a screenshot of the response

[image]

However, on the client side, it only sets the first cookie, and ignores the other two! I know this because it only sends back cookie `a` in the next request.

[image]

To add further mystery, the cookie that it does send back in the next request is absent from the developer tools completely!

[image]

I'm using `withCredentials: true` on my requests.

I can't figure out why it only sets the first cookie.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I removed both the `Path`, and the `HttpOnly` flag, but the issue still persists.

**Update 2**

I tried your example and here's the result

This is the response header, which shows all three cookies in one `Set-Cookie` header
[image]

But Firefox only sets one cookie. Same issue in Edge & Chrome

[image]

**UPDATE 3**

Thanks to @Hury Shen I've found the problem. Version 2 of Azure functions is the problem (which is what my app is built on). Version 2 sets all of the cookies in one `Set-Cookie` header, whereas version 3 has a separate header for each cookie (which is the correct way). To fix this, I'll have to migrate the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide how the variable `cookies` be initialized in your code, so I can't reproduce your problem. But I test with my code in my function, it works fine. You can refer to my code below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage();

    var cookie1 = new CookieHeaderValue("name1", "content of cookie==1111");
    cookie1.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    cookie1.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie1.Path = "/l/";

    var cookie2 = new CookieHeaderValue("name2", "content of cookie==2222");
    cookie2.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    cookie2.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie2.Path = "/l";

    var cookie3 = new CookieHeaderValue("name3", "content of cookie==3333");
    cookie3.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1);
    cookie3.HttpOnly = true;
    cookie3.Path = "/l/some-folder-path";

    resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] {cookie1, cookie2, cookie3});

    return resp;
}
```

After request the function in my browser, we can see the cookies in below screenshot:
[image]

================================**Update**=============================

[image]

Comment: Which browser did you use?

Comment: Hi @Matt I test it in IE. And I test it in Edge just now, it seems also works fine. The screenshot under "Update" of my answer is my test in Edge.

Comment: Hey @hury-shen I found the issue. V2 Azure function sets cookies differently than V3. I'll need to migrate the app to fix the problem. Thanks for your help.